# Google Maps v3 APIs Geocoding and Places Inconsistent Viewport

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm working on a Google Maps project where we want the customer to type in an Autocomplete address and then be taken to that place on the map.

My manager wants a consistent "viewport" result when compared to the viewport achieved when searching for the same place on maps.google.com.

I found an inconsistent result for a certain location, in particular for the Australian city of Sydney.

The result I get back from Places Autocomplete for Sydney looks quite zoomed in (I used the response's viewport data and call map.fitBounds(...).  I'm a first time Stackoverflow user, so I can't post images yet - instead, the effect can be seen by entering 'Sydney, New South Wales, Australia' at the following page:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Alternatively, if I use the Geocoding API instead and take the viewport data response and use that to call map.fitBounds(...), I get a zoomed out view, similar to what I would see when I look for Sydney on maps.googles.com.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions that would provide a solution that gives my customers a viewing result that is 100% consistent with maps.google.com.   For example, should I be using a different version of the Autocomplete API, or pass a special parameter?  Ideally I would prefer to not be calling the Geocoding to retrieve and override the Autocomplete viewport response, since that would double up my API traffic and double the hit on Google's servers.

I look forward to any advice anybody can offer, thank you!!!

Comment: Hello, has anybody else found the viewport to be inconsistent as per what I have described?  My manager is pressing me for a solution and I'm just about out of time, so I would be very grateful if anybody can pleas assist.  Also see more additional detail I've provided in my comment on the answer from JustWe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting the map zoom level to be consistent after the search ? 
I do android with google map. And just by looking at the code from the provided link above.
change that map.setZoom() method to the level you want might help.

I haven't done javascript google map api yet. Just taking a wide guess.

If I am answering the wrong question, please correct me.

Comment: Actually I need variable zoom levels, as achieved by using map.fitBounds(...) and passing the location's viewport values (provided by Places Autocomplete and Geocoding APIs).  Different locations require different zoom levels relevant to the type of location and the area that it takes up on the map.  For example the city of Sydney requires to be quite "zoomed out" to view the whole city as if from very high up; however the suburb of Kings Cross does not need to be zoomed out as far.  I'm trying to mimic the "relevant" zoom level effect as seen by searching for places on maps.google.com.

Comment: Thanks JustWe, yes I had to go with manually setting my zoom using setZoom.